# React Material UI issue with syled-engine resolution while running tests (Works while serve/building)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ts-jest, nrwl-nx

I'm using mui.com Material UI components with `styled-components` instead of `emotion` which is the default one.

I have updated my tsconfig.json to include

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "paths": {
      ...,
      "@mui/styled-engine": ["./node_modules/@mui/styled-engine-sc"]
    }
```

Now while I use `webpack-dev-server` or `webpack build` it gets resolved correctly

But while I run the tests I get the following error

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@emotion/styled' from '../../node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/node/index.js'

    Require stack:
      C:/LearningProjects/tech-events-uk/node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/node/index.js
      C:/LearningProjects/tech-events-uk/node_modules/@mui/system/index.js
      C:/LearningProjects/tech-events-uk/node_modules/@mui/material/node/styles/adaptV4Theme.js
      C:/LearningProjects/tech-events-uk/node_modules/@mui/material/node/styles/index.js
      C:/LearningProjects/tech-events-uk/node_modules/@mui/material/node/index.js
      src/lib/event-card/event-card.tsx
      src/lib/event-card/event-card.spec.tsx

      at Resolver.resolveModule (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/node/index.js:45:38)
```

I think possibly some jest config is missing and not much familiar with jest configurations to be used with `npm` and not `yarn`

Reference:
https://mui.com/guides/styled-engine/

Comment: Same problem here!

Comment: Did you every get this to work. Having the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my `jest.config.js` did the trick:

```
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@mui/styled-engine$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@mui/styled-engine-sc',
    },
};
```

Comment: Was there anything else you added because the above doesn't seem to work for me. I still get the error: Cannot find module '@emotion/styled' from 'node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/node/index.js'